# Fill dates from Python groupby

Tags: python, django, python-itertools

I have a collection of news article objects which I wish to display archived by distinct month.  I've used `itertools.groupby` to create a list of Python objects ordered in such a way:

```
news_grouped = [
    {'date': key, 'list': list(val)}
    for key, val in groupby(obj_list, 
                            (lambda v: datetime.datetime(v.pub_date.year, 
                                                         v.pub_date.month, 1)))
]
```

So I end up with a collection like:

```
[{'date': datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0), 
  'list': [<News: A January Article>, <News: Another January Article>]}, 
 {'date': datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 1, 0, 0), 
  'list': [<News: Happy Xmas>]}, 
 {'date': datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 1, 0, 0), 
  'list': [<News: Halloween>]}, 
 {'date': datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1, 0, 0), 
  'list': [<News: Old old old Jan 2010>]}]
```

I would like to fill the news_grouped collection so that it includes an entry for each month between the oldest article and today's date, with empty ones just having an empty list.

I realize I can do this by iterating from the oldest date to the newest date, and filling the collection, but something about that just doesn't quite sit right with me, and I'd imagine it's not very efficient either.

Is there a more elegant way of solving this?  Can anyone point me at one?

(I'm actually using Django and was using regroup, but it seems like I'm better solving this in python outside of the templates - I could of course be wrong)

Many thanks.

Ludo.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for this complicated data structure? Why not use a dictionary with months as keys and lists of news items as values?

Comment: I based it on the Django regroup template tag.  The reason I store the whole date is to that I can display the year and month in different formats in the template.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Space_C0wb0y go for a dictionary, if you like use an ordered dict which is part of the collections module since 2.7.

1. get the oldest article
2. create the dict keys mapping to empty lists by looping from oldest.pub_date to today in month steps
3. loop through all items and append to the appropriate list in the dict

Comment: I've gone with an OrderedDict.  I just thought there might be some tidier way than filling it myself.  Thanks.